# Sanity check on reflexive docker Image building?

Tags: docker

I'm using docker to compile a rather slow C++ process.  It takes about 3 hrs to build my software.  In order to speed things up I've added `ccache` into the mix.

So after my build I was doing the following:

`docker create --name=ccache LAST_IMAGE`
then using `docker cp` to copy out the `/root/.ccache` directory - tar it up and then with an `ADD` command I'd re-insert the tar into the next image when I re-built it.

I just switched to the following approach - as it seemed to use up less intermediate space on the drive:

When I invoke `docker build` I pass in a build argument

```
  77   │     - DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --force-rm
  78   │       --file devops/Dockerfile.buildAfsim
  79   │       --build-arg GIT_COMMIT=${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
  80   │       --build-arg PARENT_IMAGE=$DOCKER_REGISTRY$PARENT_IMAGE_NAME
  81   │       --build-arg LAST_BUILD_IMAGE=$DOCKER_REGISTRY$AFSIM_BUILD_IMAGE_NAME
  82   │       --tag $DOCKER_REGISTRY$AFSIM_BUILD_IMAGE_NAME .
```

The key here is that I'm passing in the image itself twice:

```
--build-arg LAST_BUILD_IMAGE=$DOCKER_REGISTRY$AFSIM_BUILD_IMAGE_NAME
--tag $DOCKER_REGISTRY$AFSIM_BUILD_IMAGE_NAME
```

This in turn will tell my docker build process to pull the last image - copy out the `cmake` and `cache` directories into the current docker context

And in my docker file I've got:

```
ARG LAST_BUILD_IMAGE
FROM ${LAST_BUILD_IMAGE} as last_build

# Pass in the base build image
ARG PARENT_IMAGE
FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}

# Copy the ccache and cmake files from the previous run in order to speed up build speeds
# This will cause issues - if we dont actualy have a last build saved somewhere but we'll deal
# with that when we get to it.
copy --from=last_build /devel/software/build /devel/software/build
copy --from=last_build /root/.ccache /root/.ccache
```

Has anybody done anything like this before?  It does make a big impact on my ci build times - but I'm wondering if there are better ways.  Thus far its the best I've come up with.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the cache directory in a volume. Run the build container as:

```
docker run -v ccache:/root/.ccache ...
```

Notice that instead of having an absolute path on the left we just have `ccache`. That creates a named volume that's not saved in any particular directory on the host system. It's only accessible by name.

Any data written to `/root/.ccache` will be automatically available in future runs when the `ccache` volume is mounted. At any time you can run `docker volume rm ccache` to clear out the cache and force a fresh build.

Comment: So the reason I chose not to go that route is that its my `docker build` command that actually compiles the c++ code - so I'd have to create a separate container and then pull the data out locally - which means I have a copy of the cache in the registry as well as a copy locally that I need to put back into the container on build -